# Why is this program unable to print thread IDs?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I know that grids are composed of blocks, and blocks are composed of threads.

So, the following source code should launch some threads. Right?

Then, why doesn't the following program print block and thread IDs?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

__global__ void my_kernel()
{
    int block_id = blockIdx.x;
    int thread_id = threadIdx.x;

    printf("\nBlock ID : %d", block_id);
    printf("\nThread ID : %d", thread_id);
}

int main()
{
    dim3 grids(1);
    dim3 blocks(1);

    my_kernel<<<grids, blocks>>>();

    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Block ID : 0
Thread ID : 0
```

How can I fix this program to launch three grids with one block each, with each block having one thread?

Comment: Huh, that is exactly what's happening. There is always exactly one grid per kernel. Your grid has one block (index 0), that one block has 1 thread (index 0). What you see is what you ask for.

Comment: @Homer512, Okay. I want to launch three Grids, then.

Comment: Do you mean 3 threads in one block? There is exactly one grid per kernel launch.

Comment: @Homer512, I want to launch three grids. Where each grid will have one block, and each block will have one thread.

Comment: I think you are confused about the terminology. A kernel launch has *one* grid. That grid consists of `N` blocks. Each block consists of `M` threads, resulting in `N * M` thread launches total. You launch a kernel with the syntax `my_kernel<<<dim3(blocks), dim3(threads)>>>()`. If you want multiple grids, you have to launch multiple kernels in parallel (in different streams) or after each other

Comment: @Homer512, *If you want multiple grids, you have to launch multiple kernels in parallel (in different streams) or after each other* --- Then show me an example.

Comment: Also the number of blocks per grid and threads per block can be three-dimensional and you can calculate your own mapping to arbitrary ids with an arbitrary number of dimensions. And you can use for loops within CUDA.

Comment: A block and thread id of 0 is a valid id.

Comment: Should the 3 grids be the same kernel, should the 3 grids run at the same time or one after the other?

Comment: Also see your other question, where you assume the number of grids has something to do with griddim, which specifies the size of the single grid as number of blocks per this grid.

Answer (score 3):

You can launch 3 different grids in parallel using different streams for each kernel launch:

```
cudaStream_t streams[3];
for (auto& stream: streams)
{
    cudaStreamCreate(&stream);

    constexpr auto DynamicSharedMemSize = 0;
    my_kernel<<<grids, blocks, DynamicSharedMemSize, stream>>>();
}
```

For more information, see [this article from NVIDIA's developer blog](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/gpu-pro-tip-cuda-7-streams-simplify-concurrency/) about CUDA streams.